# iTunes connect error "To use this application, you must first sign in to iTunes Connect and sign the relevant contracts."

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I try to sign in the application loader, and it comes out the error message said "To use this application, you must first sign in to Itunes Connect and sign the relevant contracts", and I did sign for the relevant contracts under Itunes Connect > Agreements, Tax and Banking, however I still not manage to sign in.

Comment: Same here ! Have you found any solution ?

Comment: same problem! There is no info about it anywhere..

Answer (score 55):

Don't try to launch Application Loader from Finder or desktop. Juste open it from Xcode (since last update)  : 
Xcode => Open Developer Tool.

There you'll be asked to accept some terms (prob due to new GDPR or whatever) not from itunes connect as they WRONGLY prompt you ...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but I do not have xcode installed. I am using application loader as a stand alone. How to do?

Comment: Had the exact same problem. This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, there is no way I would have figured this out on my own! Why is it so hard for Apple to make things easy for developers?

Comment: Xcode>Open Developer Tool>Application Loader. This worked for me as well. System prompted to review and sign a contract, after which I was able to sign in and upload the ipa file.

Comment: Why Apple can just give a normal warning :))

Comment: same problem as @javalove ... but I can't install xcode... mac version is too old. Other thoughts?

Comment: Yes!  Worked perfectly.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Wow what a mess, thanks buddy. Finally hit upon this post, been driving me nuts for couple dats

Comment: Work for me too